# How to use jasper reports in my project? What are the Advantages and Disadvantages of jasper reports?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jasper-reports

How do I implement and use jasper reports in my JSP/Servlet project? What is the advantage/disadvantages of using jasper reports?

Comment: Try searching for "jasper report servlet" and you should get lots on answers.

Here is a similar question about the draw backs of jasper reports. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729118/what-are-the-drawbacks-with-jasper-reports/2736405#2736405

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See their Homepage for tutorials on how to implement JasperReports.

If you want to know advantages vs. disadvantages you need something to compare it to. I believe you know the comparison results vs. creating report manually (without a report engine), so I assume you want a comparison with the other big player, namely Crystal Reports.

CrystalReports:

- Widely used, large community
- Some bugs in Java report editor and they missed to make some properties editable which can be edited by the native report editor.
- If stuck, you don't have the source to fix it. You WILL get stuck.
- Programmers hate it, Managers love it.
- Stupidest image handling capabilities imaginable for a product with this reach. Scale an image proportionally? Sorry, no go.

JasperReports:

- Widely used, also large community
- Programmers love it, managers don't like it.

I would DEFENITELY GO WITH JASPER if I had to decide this again. And i WILL implement Jasper as a secondare report engine in our app, when I get the time to do this, because CR sucks big time.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an excellent feature comparison](http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html) of JasperReports, BIRT and Pentaho